# MS Office: drag and drop outlook item into a shortcut to run it

Tags: windows, outlook, drag-and-drop

I would like to be able to drag and drop a Microsoft Office Outlook item into a **non-running** application or a shortcut: the application must start with the dropped item as start item, without first running the application and then, in another step dropping the item.

By default, looks like to drop Outlook Items into a user application (or shortcut link) is not enabled, like for notepad, explorer and other Microsoft applications. Maybe there is a registry setting required to define that capability for a user application.
To test, drag-and-drop any item from Outlook into a dormant Notepad (or .txt file), word, excel or desktop, the item will generate action from the application (create a shortcut or open de app).  With some others, including your own, the drag-and-drop fail.

To start an application, with a random (disk) file as parameter, from 'explorer', *drag-and-* **drop** a regular file into the shortcut (or the .exe): the program is run as `xxxx.exe "%1"`where %1 will be the file location; how can we do the same dragging from outlook?

Dropping outlook items into a **running** application is straightforward: on the application **drag-over event** you determine the kind of item looking at the clipboard Data.GetFormats and then, either open the file or use the outlook 'inspector' to get the item.